# How to get the xml tag name when iterating through a XMLList in ActionScript?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

What I want to do is loop through an xml file, and assign the contents of each node to a static variable with the same name.

So for instance for

```xml
<item1>blah<item1>
<item2>tasdsddssda</item2>
<item3>asdasdasd</item3>
```

```as
var xmlNodes:XMLList = xml.children();

for (var i = 0; i < xmlNodes.length(); i++) {
     ClassName[tagName] = xmlNodes[i];
}
```

How do I get the tagName for the tag?

Have been looking through the documentation for [`XML`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html) and [`XMLList`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XMLList.html#text()) but couldn't spot how to do it unless I'm having one of my blind moments. I tried .name but that didn't work. I spotted that I could do it with [`toXMLString()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XMLList.html#toXMLString()) but thought there must be a nicer way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```as
var xmlNodes:XMLList = xml.children();

for each (var item:XML in xmlNodes) {
  ClassName[item.name()] = item;
}
```

See [the livedocs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html).

Comment: Brilliant, didn't try it with the brackets. ClassName[item.name()] = item; I was trying to achieve. Thanks :)